# mat slide toggle initially set to true always even if it is bind to a property whole value is false

Tags: angular

I am using a mat toggle button and it is two way binded with a property whose initial value is false with [(ngModel)], but the toggle button automatically sets to true even with two way binding for the first time, when i remove [(ngModel)] and bind with [checked] property it shows correct results but with [(ngModel)] it does not.

```
<div *ngIf="agent.attributes[i].type == 'Boolean'">
                  <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="agent.attributes[i].value == 'true' ? true : false" 
                  [(ngModel)]="agent.attributes[i].value">{{agent.attributes[i].value}}</mat-slide-toggle>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your modal too?

Comment: "type" : "Boolean", "value" : "false"   ,,,, it is binded with a string

Comment: What is the type of agent.attributes[i].value?

Comment: its type is string,